# Adding blank page between letters when pages is odd

Tags: forms, postscript

I am converting a pre-existing postscript form from simplex to duplex and need to force a blank page when the page count of a letter is odd.

I'm using <>setpagedevice after Main Routine.  My document prints duplex, but does not separate letters.  A letter will start on the back page of a letter when it is odd numbered.  Here's an update of what I am looking at:

```
% Main Routine
/yPos yInit def   % No StartPage means no overlay on banner page
<</Duplex true /Tumble false>>setpagedevice
{ fileSrc sBuf readline
  /lineCnt 1 lineCnt add def 
  not { fileSrc closefile Trailer quit } if    % End of File?  Yes, print  last page, go away
  dup length 0 gt                              %   No, Empty line?
  { dup 0 get 12 eq                            %     No, End of Page?
  { SeqNumber 0 gt {BarcodePrint} if         %       Yes, Print Barcode if Seq > 0
  showpage                                 %           print the page
  dup length 1 exch 1 sub getinterval      %           skip page feed character
  StartPage                                %           Start next page
  /pageCnt 1 pageCnt add def
  } if
  } if
  lMargin yPos moveto show
  /yPos yPos yDelta sub def
} loop
```

I have the document printing in duplex, but the letters don't separate correctly.  I'm new to Postscript as our support has left.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute an extra showpage when the page count is odd, and you have reached the end of the document. I'm assuming that is when the string contains "STATE OF WASHINGTON", because that's the condition where you reset the page count.

So before you reset the PageNumber to 1, you should check its current value, and if its odd, execute showpage.

Note that your StartPage procedure does a great deal, without more information its not realistically possible to determine what its all for. Also, we've no idea under what conditions this will be called, it clearly expects a string argument, it runs some other code (not presented here) under some conditions, etc.